why in the paint it's drawing small squares and not circles?
private void PictureBoxPoints_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (pictureBoxPoints.Image != null)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = pictureBoxPoints.Image as Bitmap;
        double xFactor = (double)bitmap.Width / pictureBoxPoints.Width;
        double yFactor = (double)bitmap.Height / pictureBoxPoints.Height;
        double scaleFactor = Math.Max(xFactor, yFactor); // Ensure uniform scaling

        foreach (System.Drawing.Point point in _dotPoints)
        {
            int ellipseSize = (int)(5 / scaleFactor); // Ensure uniform scaling for the size
            int ellipseX = (int)(point.X / scaleFactor) - ellipseSize / 2;
            int ellipseY = (int)(point.Y / scaleFactor) - ellipseSize / 2;

            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, new Rectangle(ellipseX, ellipseY, ellipseSize, ellipseSize));
        }
    }
}


Show us a screenshot.

ellipseSize / 2 <-- This division will be integer-division, but the rest of your program uses double-division - this may have an undesirable effect.

You might want to set e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;: Graphics.SmoothingMode Property.

double is good for WPF. In WinForms, you use float for drawing. Use RectangleF, PointF etc.

We need to know how small is 'small' !? Also: Maybe 5f would be better than 5

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.fillellipse?view=net-8.0#system-drawing-graphics-fillellipse(system-drawing-brush-system-drawing-rectanglef)

If you meant square-y circles:

The rendering system doesn't antialias things by default and so your circles are too small they might appear as squares.
The fix is to set your graphics' SmoothingMode to AntiAlias or HighQuality:
e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

This is the same code, but with antialiasing:

Note: I made my own points list with the same name since you didn't provide the _dotPoints.
